# Alternative to bitmapdata for snapshotting?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm currently loading a remote swf through as3 (with a domain policy to allow all from that domain - the policy file can't be changed by myself), that i want to take a snapshot of. The problem is that the main swf that i load, is loading child swf's from another domain that does not have the allow all policy turned on.. This makes the snapshot feature call a "sandbox security" error. I'm wondering if there's an alternative to the bitmapdata draw function to still take a "snapshot" without conflicting the sandbox security.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are allowed to load data from the domain in question, do the following:

1. load swf as binary data using URLLoader and URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY
2. load binary content into display object using Loader and loadBytes()

After that you should be able to `draw()` that swf's content.

**EDIT** Example of this technique.

Just copy and paste the code below into a blank fla, compile and place the resulting swf somewhere over http (when testing locally, both draw() calls will be a success, so you will not see the difference).

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

var onBinaryComplete:Function = function (event:Event) : void
{
    trace("onBinaryComplete()");
    var loader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
    var bytes:ByteArray = loader.data as ByteArray;
    trace(bytes.length+" bytes");
    bytesLoader.loadBytes(bytes);
}

var onBytesComplete:Function = function (event:Event) : void
{
    trace("onBytesComplete()");
    var info:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0x8000FF00);
    // this will not fail, you'll see an image
    bmp.draw(info.content);
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
    bitmap.x += 100;
    bitmap.y += 100;
    stage.addChild(bitmap); 
}

var onDirectLoadComplete:Function = function (event:Event) : void
{
    trace("onDirectLoadComplete()");
    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0x80FF0000);
    // this must fail, you'll get an exception
    bmp.draw(event.target.content);
    stage.addChild(new Bitmap(bmp));
}

var binaryLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
binaryLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
binaryLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBinaryComplete);
binaryLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://noregret.org/test/wrk.swf"));

var bytesLoader:Loader = new Loader();
bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBytesComplete);

var directLoader:Loader = new Loader();
directLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDirectLoadComplete);
directLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://noregret.org/test/wrk.swf"));
```

Loading of data crossdomain.xml: http://noregret.org/crossdomain.xml, but you have no control over loaded swf content when loading it directly. Loading bytes and then the content solves the problem.

Comment: I'm also trying to show a preview of said swf, but i'm oblivious on how to convert the bytearray into a movieclip. Any help?

Comment: Create `new Loader()` use `loader.loadBytes()` method, and wait for `Even.COMPLETE` from `loader.contentLoaderInfo`. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29

Comment: Used that, i'm getting no errors, and no loaded swf. While i can normally load the swf with no issues, just no snapshot allowed.

`ldr.loadBytes(raw.data);` and in the complete event: `loaded_swf = MovieClip(evt.target.bytes);`

Comment: This line is wrong: `loaded_swf = MovieClip(evt.target.bytes);`. After loading bytes and getting Event.COMPLETE you can reference loaded swf as if you normally loaded it with load() method. `loaded_swf = MovieClip(evt.target.content)`.

Comment: When using a normal load. My debug log would show things like `[SWF] /clothes/bg/bg_10438411_bg.swf - 5363 bytes after decompression`. When using binarydata, these don't show up either.

Comment: I've edited my answer adding complete example. Just copy and paste the code into a blank fla, compile and place it somewhere over http.

Comment: `http://image2.tinierme.com/selfy.swf?face=10495682&hair=10375386&accef=0&acceh=0&top=10438371&bottom=10326941&accen=10438483&back=10438521&hat=10437831&shoe=0&coat=10423751&bg=10438411&bodycolor=17000192&mode=fitting` as url gives blank bitmap. Also a blank movieclip if added into that. With direct load the movieclip is loaded correctly.

Comment: Result also depends on what you are loading. If you load a complicated app, it may not be available for drawing right away. May be it loads something in turn, or has a defered initialization routine. Try waiting before drawing. And chances are, that you need to use matrix as a second argument of draw() to translate what you are drawing into appropriate position (like when you are drawing a clip with a registration point displaced somehow).

Comment: Added a button to initialize the snapshot function later. Even after waiting 20 seconds, still blank.

Comment: If you are talking about image2.tinierme.com/selfy.swf, then you have no chance of accomplishing what you aim for, because the don't permit data loading from domains other than *.tinierme.com. Binary data won't load.

Comment: Figures. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Oh, I've forgotten the link. http://image2.tinierme.com/crossdomain.xml -- that is why I'm saying they don't permit data loading.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much what the sandbox is for. So you can't make snapshots from data you don't own. This is a lame answer, but [as the docs point out](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29), the only way to get around it is by using AIR.

If you have access to the other domain or you know the people controlling it, you might be able to place a [crossdomain.xml](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/security2_04.html#139879) at their site.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the asset through some proxy (hosted on your own server). A lot of hosting companies don't allow hosting any proxy scripts, even if it's meant to load assets for applications.